# summarise mean of a specific column in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to summarise a grouped data.frame without knowing the name of the column. But what I know is, that the feature is always at position 3 (column) in this data.frame, is that possible?

```
df <- data_frame(date = rep(c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03"), 2),
             group = rep(c("A", "B"), 3),
             temperature =  runif(6, -10, 30),
             percipitation = runif(6, 0,5)
             )

parameter <- "perc"

df1 <- df %>%
  select(date, group, starts_with(parameter)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(
  avg = mean(percipitation)
 )
```

In this example the code works, but of course only for the parameter 'perc' and not for 'temp' or so.

```
 avg = mean(df[[3]])
```

or something like this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: colnames(df)[3] gives you the name of the third column, which you can then use...

Comment: I also did think about this, but with colnames(df)[3] I get a string and for the function-call I can't use this string... avg = mean(colnames(df)[3]) does not work. How would you use it?

Comment: This might be easiest actually:
     df[,c(2,4)] %>% ddply(.(group),numcolwise(mean) )

Comment: Thanks Jon! That works and is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You could keep just the grouping variable and the third column using `select(group, 3)`. The function `summarise_all()` can then be used to calculate the mean.

```
df %>%
    select(group, 3) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise_all(
        funs(mean)
    )
```

Comment: Hi David! Many thanks for your answer, that works too. I didn't knew that it is possible to access the column only by its number (select(group, 3))... So this solution is really logical and usable.

Comment: Great, happy to help!